# Updating ListView with Multiple Gridview C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a single ListView Control and couple of Buttons in a WPF Application. Based on the button click i want to populate different sets of results from different classes into the listview . All these different classes are wrapped inside a single class (ReportClass)as shown below. The way, i am trying to achieve this is by Changing the GridView and ItemSource of listview  from code-behind. This code almost works..because the listview results change on button clicks , but displays only the class name instead of the results in the List of that Class.

P.S: I am no expert in XAML/WPF . But, if there are simpler solutions ..answers are welcome. Thanks

Here is my code:

```
public class animalTypes1
{
    public string type1name { get; set; };      
}

public class animalTypes2
{
    public string type2name { get; set; };
}

public class ReportClass
{
    public List<animalTypes1> animaltype1 = new List<animalTypes1>();
    public List<animalTypes2> animaltype2 = new List<animalTypes2>();

}

    private ObservableCollection<ReportClass> _DynamicreportClass;
    public ObservableCollection<ReportClass> _DynamicReportSetClass
    {
        get
        {
            if (_DynamicreportClass == null)
            {
                _DynamicreportClass = new ObservableCollection<ReportClass>();
            }
            return _DynamicreportClass;
        }

    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           


        GridView g1 = new GridView();
        g1.AllowsColumnReorder = true;
        g1.ColumnHeaderToolTip = "mammals";

        GridViewColumn g1c = new GridViewColumn();
        g1c.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("type1name");
        g1c.Header = "AnimalReport1Header";
        g1c.Width = 120;
        g1.Columns.Add(g1c);


        GridView g1x = new GridView();
        g1x.AllowsColumnReorder = true;
        g1x.ColumnHeaderToolTip = "mammals";

        GridViewColumn g1cx = new GridViewColumn();
        g1cx.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("type2name");
        g1cx.Header = "AnimalReport2Header";
        g1cx.Width = 120;
        g1x.Columns.Add(g1cx);


        ReportClass allreports = new ReportClass();
        allreports.animaltype1.Add(new animalTypes1() { type1name = "Mammals" });
        allreports.animaltype2.Add(new animalTypes2() { type2name = "Reptiles" });

        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, new System.Action(delegate ()
        {
            _DynamicReportSetClass.Add(allreports);

        }));

    private void btn1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ReportGrid.ItemsSource = _DynamicreportClass[0].animaltype1;
        ReportGrid.View = g1;
    }

    private void btn_click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ReportGrid.ItemsSource = _DynamicreportClass[0].animaltype2;
        ReportGrid.View = g1x;

    }
```

Here is XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <WrapPanel Margin="0,0,0,125">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Checkbtn" Click="btn1_click"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Checkbtn" Click="btn_click2"/>
    </WrapPanel>

    <ListView 
        x:Name="ReportGrid" 
        Margin="0,199,0,0"  
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView/>
        </ListView.View>         
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: 1. XAML can't bind to fields, only to properties. Add { get; set; } to all of your fields so they become properties. 2. Don't do anything in code behind at all. 3. Please include your XAML. I'm not sure what "changing the gridview and itemsource" means. Is this a master-detail relationship?

Comment: added get and set as you mentioned, but no success

Comment: Do `animaltype1` and `animaltype2` in ReportClass have get/set now?

Comment: no, the lists don't have it. But how to add get and set to a list . can you share a piece of code?

Comment: `private List<animalTypes1> _animaltype1 = new List<animalTypes1>(); public List<animalTypes1> animaltype1 { get { return _animaltype1; } }`

Comment: @EdPlunkett Added get/set to lists as well...but doesn't work

Comment: Just a recommendation: use the MVVM Pattern...

Comment: Listen to @Mat -- just look up MVVM pattern. Write a view model, implement INotifyPropertyChanged on it, use ObservableCollection instead of List. All animal classes should inherit a Name property from a common base class. Get rid of the ListView. GridView IS collection view already, just use it (or else just use a ListView). Bind the gridview's ItemsSource to a SelectedAnimalList property of your ViewModel, then select a collection to display by having buttons assign other collections to SelectedAnimalList.

Comment: i know very little about MVVM pattern. I have just moved from win forms to  WPF/XAML . And i am already confused with so many things to study in xaml. It takes me a little while to study and implement something. Right now, i am stuck with urgent job task and i don't have time to study any new concept. Correct if i am wrong,  but as far as i read and remember from some website... GridView doesn't exist in WPF. But, we can get the Gridview functionality inside the LIstview Control.  Thanks

Comment: GridView exists in WPF. You already used one. Don't put it in a ListView. Here's a question with some decent basic examples of MVVM in WPF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124294/wpf-mvvm-ef-simple-example Anyway if you don't have time for this right now, then right now may not be the best time for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good reason to follow MVVM pattern to separate view from behavior. For current case, it is better to implement triggered style for ListView:

```
<ListView 
    Margin="0,199,0,0"  
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source1}"/>
            <Setter Property="View">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" ColumnHeaderToolTip="mammals">
                        <GridViewColumn Header="AnimalReport1Header" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding type1name}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSource2}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source2}"/>
                    <Setter Property="View">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" ColumnHeaderToolTip="mammals">
                                <GridViewColumn Header="AnimalReport2Header" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding type2name}"/>
                            </GridView>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Style>
</ListView>
```

And change implementation of MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    #endregion

    private ObservableCollection<animalTypes1> _source1 = new ObservableCollection<animalTypes1> {
        new animalTypes1() { type1name = "Mammals" } };

    public ObservableCollection<animalTypes1> Source1
    {
        get { return _source1; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<animalTypes2> _source2 = new ObservableCollection<animalTypes2> {
        new animalTypes2() { type2name = "Reptiles" } };

    public ObservableCollection<animalTypes2> Source2
    {
        get { return _source2; }
    }

    private bool _isSource2;

    public bool IsSource2
    {
        get { return _isSource2; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isSource2)
            {
                _isSource2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSource2");
            }
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;          
    }

    private void btn1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsSource2 = false;
    }

    private void btn_click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsSource2 = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. The code works wonderfully. I will use this approach now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug. The reason for the listview not being updated with gridview was because of Gridview instance "g1" and ""g1x" . Mistake by me, that i had instantiated i had "g1" and "g1x" as null . And, in the constructor method instantiated once again which did not update the publicly declared instance.